# Travis CI and Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, travis-ci, laravel-dusk

I have just added the tests with [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/dusk).
Everything works if I test on my pc. I thus set up a travis.yml file :

```
language: php
sudo: required
dist: trusty

php: 
  - 7.1
  - 7.2

addons:
  chrome: stable

services:
  - mysql

install:
  - cp .env.travis .env
  - mysql -e 'create database homestead_test;'
  - travis_retry composer self-update
  - travis_retry composer install --no-interaction
  - php artisan key:generate
  - php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

before_script:
  - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &
  - php artisan serve &

script:
  - php artisan code:analyse --level=7
  - php artisan dusk
  - vendor/bin/phpunit

notifications:
  email: false
```

However, when I push on Github I obtains errors : [show travis errors](https://travis-ci.org/quentinGeeraert/quentin59-website/jobs/450558244)

I does not understand to make how so that my tests work on travis.

Would anybody know how to help me on this point? Best Regards, Quentin

**Update :**
The exact commit on [github](https://github.com/quentinGeeraert/quentin59-website/commit/eb759c780a6e5d3a5b9a83860314dae8cefe3ac3)

Comment: Put `APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000` in your `.env.travis` file.

Comment: In my .env.travis i have already APP_URL like this [.env.travis](https://github.com/quentinGeeraert/quentin59-website/blob/9b1c0e3df073a2f08aa6438c444fcbad24706114/.env.travis)

Comment: Why is that commit not in any of the branches?

Comment: I had temporarily remove the branch because there was too much Travis trial on. Now you can see my files [here](https://github.com/quentinGeeraert/quentin59-website/tree/feature/webtests)

Comment: I changed the post to specify the build travis and commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `SESSION_DRIVER=array` in your `.env.travis` file, change it to `SESSION_DRIVER=file`.

The login tests aren't working because the sessions vanish after each request.

Comment: I change SESSION_DRIVER=array to SESSION_DRIVER=file in my .env.travis and the result is [that](https://travis-ci.org/quentinGeeraert/quentin59-website/jobs/450580962) Thank you very much